# Адаптивная верстка при маштабировании страницы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте, у меня возник вопрос, дело в том, что я хочу сделать так, что бы изображение(или div или любой дугой элемент) изменяло свой размер не только во время изменение размера окна браузера, но и при его масштабировании (ctrl + +). И в этом моменте я встретился с проблемой, ведь если я укажу в стиле width:100%, то этому стилю будет фиолетово на масштаб окна, и он просто будет все время растянут на всю длину окна, зато можно изменять размеры окна и типо адаптивно. Но вот если поставить width:100px, то тут теперь другая ситуация, с маштабом картинка уменьшается, а вот с уменьшением размера окна она, как и ожидается остается неизменной. Можно ли как-нибудь предусмотреть "положительное" выполнение обоих пунктов с помощью html css или даже JS Jquery?

Comment: Ну так всё работает как задумано...

Comment: В смысле? Я знаю, что оно работает так, как и должно, но я ищу пусть, который описал в вопросе

Comment: Ну тут можно предложить только использовать `@media`. В зависимости от разрешения задавать ширину элемента. Например `@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    /* STYLES HERE */
}
` [media w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно все обернуть в глобальный контейнер и приписывает ему ширину в пикселях:

```
funtcion setWidth(){
  $('#global').width($(window).width());
}
```

И запускать на `doc ready` и `window resize`;

Тогда он зумиться будет вместе.

Answer (score 0):

указывайте размер в `vw` и `vh` и будет вам счастье.